# Erased System Path Variables

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, psexec

I was writing a batch file that was supposed to automatically set up a computer to receive "psexec" remote commads. Unluckly i didn't really pay attention to what i was writing and i wrote this command and then ran It:

```
setx /M Path "C:\Windows\System32\PSTools"
```

You can imagine what happened... I erased all the other path variables! Then, panicking, mis-reading an online-forum, I restarted the computer. I had no backups, no saving points and neither, obviously, opened cmd's or powershell's session. My questions are:

1. Is there still a way to recover the path variables i lost or they're gone forever?
2. If they're gone, is there a way for me to like "re-write" them or just get a list of the missing ones?

I know that my questions will seem stupid to the experienced programmers and i apologise for that, but I actually started this project with almost zero skills in bat, cmd, and the other stuffs...
Thanks to everyone that will help <3

Comment: Try asking on Super User and/or, Server Fault as well. May not get much info, if any, from a programming site. Take a look at [this Article](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/). May get you in the right direction if they're still in your registry. Summarized: `Get-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" `.

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for replying, but unfortunately i had disabled even the automatic restore point creator and even the other folders and registers that you told to check, i found out that are empty and containing no old path variables. Either way i really thank you, for trying to give help. I’ll ask the same on Super User and Server Vault.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try the following in a Command Prompt window, ```For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %H In ('^"For %G In (CurrentControlSet ControlSet001 ControlSet002 ControlSet003^) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\%G\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V "Path" 2^>NUL^"') Do @Echo %I```